# cout is in bad state after cancel a thread

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I created two thread and canceled one of them before joining them:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
using namespace std;

void *func_1 (void *arg)
{
    for (;;) {
        cout << "1" << endl;
        sleep (1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *func_2 (void *arg)
{
    for (;;) {
        cout << "222" << endl ;
        sleep (1);
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main (void)
{
    pthread_t thread_1, thread_2;
    assert (pthread_create (&thread_1, NULL, func_1, NULL) == 0);
    assert (pthread_create (&thread_2, NULL, func_2, NULL) == 0);
    pthread_cancel (thread_1);
    pthread_join (thread_1, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_2, NULL);
}
```

The output is:

```bash
1
222
```

It is in blocking status.
I find both `cout.bad()` and `cout.fail()` is true. If using `printf()`, it works well.

It can works well if execute `cout.clear()`.

I wonder why the cout is in bad state.

Comment: Please do not spam the tags, this is C++ code

Comment: Writing to `cout` is not thread-safe. You need mutual exclusion between the threads.

Comment: Side note: I do not recommend that you use the `assert` macro when the side-effects of the macro are required. The line `assert (pthread_create (&thread_1, NULL, func_1, NULL) == 0);` will do nothing (i.e. it won't call `pthread_create`) when `NDEBUG` is defined, which is often the case in release builds.

Comment: use standard  library threads

Comment: The #1 rule of `pthread_cancel()` is "Never call `pthread_cancel()`".  Thread cancellation is deeply unsafe.  There are ways to make your threads handle cancellation more robustly, but they are a lot of work, and they do not produce complete safety.  So again, do not call `pthread_cancel()`.  Ever.

Comment: @Barmar -- `std::cout` is thread-safe in that insertions into the stream do not create data races. The problem with writing from multiple threads is that the output from different threads can be interleaved.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's too sad.Without pthread_cancel, how can I terminate a thread from another?

Comment: @sixsixqaq, *cooperatively*, if at all possible.  And if that's not possible then you are probably best off terminating the whole process instead of trying to cancel a single thread.  Typically, a cooperative thread termination involves one thread setting a shared "should terminate" flag that the other periodically checks.

Answer (score 3):

```
pthread_cancel (thread_1);
```

`pthread_cancel` is a C library POSIX function.

It is incompatible with any non-trivial C++ class. `pthread_cancel` knows absolutely nothing, whatsoever, about any C++ class, its constructors or its destructors.

Such as `std::cout` from the C++ library.

Using `pthread_cancel`, with an execution thread that uses C++ classes, like `std::cout` results in undefined behavior.

> I wonder why the cout is in bad state.

Because you cannot use `cout` with C library POSIX threads, in this manner. There are no solutions, there are no workarounds (well, technically it might be possible to use it safely but with a lot, a lot of work and a huge pile of code, and you don't want to go there).

You will not find much information about POSIX threads in any modern C++ textbook which will, instead, present and explain how to use `std::thread` in modern C++ code.

Comment: actually, outputting to cout from different threads is ok in the sense it won't corrupt the stream, but the output will probably be interleaved in strange ways